# Angular2: Access class variable within anonymous function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this but I can't seem to find it. Here is my code

```
export class UserLoginComponent {
private user: User;
public authService: AuthService;

constructor(private cognitoConfigs: CognitoUtil, authService: AuthService) {
    this.user = new User();
    this.authService = authService;
}

authenticate() {

    // Some work being done here
    let cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);

    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {

        onSuccess: function(result: any) {
            this.authService.login(this.user, result);
        },
        onFailure: function(err: any) {
            console.log(err.message);
        },

    });

}
}
```

**Problem**: In the onSuccess callback I can't access the `this.authService` variable which belongs to it's parent class.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't use `function ()` because it changes the scope of `this`.

Arrow functions retain the scope of `this`

```
    onSuccess: (result: any) => {
        this.authService.login(this.user, result);
    },
    onFailure: (err: any) => {
        console.log(err.message);
    },
```

Answer (score 12):

The problem here is that the success callback function is in a different lexical environment. This is why in ES6+ functions can be defined using arrow functions =>.

```
onSuccess:(result: any) => {
        this.authService.login(this.user, result);
}
```

or assign **this** to a variable outside the scope of the function with the ES5 syntax:

```
var self = this;

onSuccess: function(result: any) {
    self.authService.login(this.user, result);
}
```