# *ngIf with accessing nested element

Tags: angular

I have a `div` I want to toggle with a button click event. Toggling works fine, but when I try to change the `src` of an inner element it says it can't find it. Why is this? Is the innerHTML not accessible with `*ngIf`? I'm new to Angular.

page.html:

```
<button (click)="click()">Click me</button>
<div *ngIf="clicked">
    <img id="selector"/>
</div>
```

script.ts:

```
export class ButtonClick {
    clicked = false;
    click() {
        this.clicked = true;
        document.getElementById('selector').src = 'clicked.jpg';
    }
}
```

Comment: First change *nfIf to *ngIf , in your question , question's title and code , there is no such thing in Angular 1 to 5

Comment: Sorry, changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing the DOM this way in Angular is discouraged. Prefer view bindings instead of imperative DOM modification:

```
<img [src]="imageSrc"/>
```

```
export class ButtonClick {
  clicked = false

  imageSrc:string;

  click() {
    this.clicked = true

    this.imageSrc = 'clicked.jpg'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That sounds logical. My real situation is a QR code being generated on the click event. I'm trying to set it, but this.imgSrc is not available in the callback function. Any idea how I can access the class variable from the callback?

Comment: You need to use `(x) => { this.xxx ...; })` instead of `function(x) { this.xxx ...; }` for `this.` to work. Or if you pass a callback reference then `foo(this.myCallback.bind(this))`. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I've got a working solution; I've changed the callback from `function() { ..}` to `() => { .. }` after reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575370/angular2-access-class-variable-within-anonymous-function/39575581 but not sure if that is the correct way.